# how do I convert a negative number into a positive one?

Tags: google-sheets, negative-number

I want to show positive movement in numbers. In my case moving from 4 to 3 is positive movement.

In my Google Sheets, I have 4 in cell B1 and 3 in C1. The percent change value is 1 and percent change is 33% improvement. If I use this formula =(b1-a1)/b1 I get -33%. What formula do I use to get 33% as the returned percent?

Answer (score 1):

Try using ABS() function. Something like this:

```
ABS((b1-a1)/b1)
```

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work. it returned #VALUE!

Comment: I am not really sure why you get #VALUE. Are you sure that you are using correct cells? In your example, you said that you have 4 in B1 and 3 in C1, but you are using A1 in formula. Anyway, ABS function should give you positive number whether you pass it positive or negative number.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=((B1-A1)/B1)*-1
```